# Python 3.4 socket programming errors

Tags: sockets, python-3.4

I'm working on scripts to test UDP throughput and came across this article:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/

I have two servers running CentOS 7.4 on x86_64 hardware, and both with Python 3.4 installed.

I'm able to get the "server" started/listening using the `recvmsg` method, however, I'm running into multiple errors with the client and the `sendmsg` method.

Initially, I was getting this error:

```
# python3.4 ~/scripts/udp_send.py
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/scripts/udp_send.py", line 14, in <module>
    fd.sendmsg(["\x00" * 32] * 1024)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

After some digging, I modified the code to encode the string to bytes, but then ran into this error:

```
# python3.4 ~/scripts/udp_send.py
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/scripts/udp_send.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = packet.encode()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I found a post around having to call encode on the `[0]` element of the list. So I tried that, and then saw this error:

```
# python3.4 ~/scripts/udp_send.py
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/scripts/udp_send.py", line 16, in <module>
    fd.sendmsg(data)
TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

I'm relatively new to Python (come from Perl), and this is my first attempt at socket programming in general.

Will be happy to provide any additional info needed.

Thanks in advance for input.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with some more code changes:

`packet = ["\x00" * 32] * 64`

Then I encoded as:

`packet = packet[0].encode()`

I was then able to send the packets using

`fd.sendmsg([packet])`

This would've worked initially had I enclosed "packet" in square brackets`[` `]` initially.

Hope someone finds this helpful.